# SQL count from table by month before

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Good morning!

I try to COUNT rows in my table 'audit' in column 'audit_process_completed' based on the months. The value in the column 'audit_process_completed' is a date format: YYYY-MM-DD. To get the COUNT of the current month i use the code below. Is there a function or possibility to say something like: "MONTH(CURDATE(**-1**)) and so on? I would like to have the COUNT for each last six months.

Edit: I have from another function the month value (eg. January -> 01) available. May be i can use this value for a select function.

Expected output is the number of rows where the date in column 'audit_process_completed' is in the selection.

Development Enviroment: MySQL Xampp Local

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `audit` 
WHERE uid = 10 
 AND cid = 12345 
 AND MONTH(`audit_process_completed`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
 AND YEAR(`audit_process_completed`) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: which SQL are using MySQL, SQL Server ? Also show us the expected output.

Comment: At the moment i am on a local Xammp server with MySQL

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to show one row with the cumulated count of the last six months? Or one row per month for the last six months, but with the count of each month's previous month? Or something else still?

Comment: Sorry may be i was not specific enough. I want to have only the sum (number) of rows from the selection. I will want to use six SQL queries => "current months -1", current month -2" and so on. I use this data as input for my bar graph. is this more clear for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See

```
SELECT SUM(    MONTH(`audit_process_completed`) = MONTH(CURDATE()) 
           AND YEAR(`audit_process_completed`) = YEAR(CURDATE())) AS count_this_month,
       SUM(    MONTH(`audit_process_completed`) = MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
           AND YEAR(`audit_process_completed`) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS count_prev_month
FROM `audit` 
WHERE uid = 10 
 AND cid = 12345
```

You may add more output fields with different months intervals substractions.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you. This is what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, If I have understood your request completely. My query gets the months from current month - 7 until current month - 1 and shows their counts. To get the months, we need some calculations. To get one result row per month, we need `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
 YEAR(audit_process_completed) AS year,
 MONTH(audit_process_completed) AS month,
 COUNT(*) 
FROM audit
WHERE uid = 10 
 AND cid = 12345 
 AND audit_process_completed >= LAST_DAY(current_date) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 8 month
 AND audit_process_completed < LAST_DAY(current_date) + INTERVAL 1 day - INTERVAL 1 month
GROUP BY
 YEAR(audit_process_completed),
 MONTH(audit_process_completed)
ORDER BY year, month;
```

Comment: Thank you Thorsten! Akina helped me already with the required query.